# Approaches on how to partition a list

Tags: algorithm, greedy

Let's say I have n elements with value `x[i]`. Let the sum of all the values be denoted as X and we enforce that every element be `x[i] <= X/2`. Now given the array `x[]`, how can I partition it into two groups (of at least size 1) such that the sum of each group is less than or equal to 2X/3?

I've been stumped on this problem for a while. I found some cases where this actually impossible to do but otherwise I have only delved into the greedy approach: put an element `x[i]` into the partition with the smallest cumulative sum. Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Does greedy method with putting elements in **decreasing order** into the partition with the smallest cumulative sum work for this case?

Answer (score 0):

Are certain that you're found counterexamples? My math might be wrong, but it seems that it'd be impossible to construct such a list. Lets note that for a list of three elements `a <= b <= c`, we can partition them as so `[a, b], [c]`. This is because for `a + b` to be larger than 2/3 of the sum, we'd have `(a + b) * 3 > 2 * (a + b + c)` or `a + b > 2 * c`, which means `a` and/or `b` would need to be larger than `c`.

With this in mind, we group our numbers into three bins, each such that its sum is less than `N/2`. Note that if we had four elements `a <= b <= c <= d`, we could partition them as `[a, b], [c], [d]`. Repeating the logic as before, for `a + b` to be larger than `N/2`, we'd need `(a + b) * 2 > (a + b + c + d)` or `a + b > c + d`, which implies `a` and/or `b` must be larger than `c`.

We can repeat this logic indefinitely from here. Taking our list as `x`, for `a + b` to be larger than `N/2`, we'd need `(a + b) * 2 > sum(x)`, which is not possible for a list with `2` or more elements larger than both `a` and `b` (which is the case for all lists of length 4 or more).

Applying this recursive logic, we can build up way up from `n` bins to three bins, treat those as the `a, b, c` numbers from the first paragraph, and construct our answer that way.

Algorithmically, create a bunch of nodes containing each element in the array (as a list of length one), and the sum (equal to the element itself, for now). Insert these into a min heap, with the sum as the key. Pop the min two, merge them (concatenate the element lists, add the sums) and push back into the min heap. Rinse and repeat until you have two nodes in your heap. They now contain your solution.

Comment: A list like [3,3,3] is an example.

Comment: @AyumuKasugano how so? I'd group it as `[3, 3], [3]`, the first sums to `6`, which equals 2/3 of the total (`9`).

Comment: Your post says "sum of each group is less than **or equal** to 2X/3"

Comment: Exactly? Each group in your partition is less than or equal to 2X/3?

Comment: @AyumuKasugano maybe I'm misunderstanding. Aren't all groups *supposed* to be less than or equal to 2X/3?

Comment: Yes. In your partition, both groups have a sum of less than or equal to (2/3)*9. The list [3,3,3] can only be partitioned in [3,3] and [3] since each group must have at least one element.

Comment: @AyumuKasugano I see. I misunderstood- I initially thought you were presenting `[3, 3, 3]` as a counterexample to the above method.